# How to contact a page owner over a request release

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

So I am currently in https://www.facebook.com/NAME_OF_BUSINESS/settings/?tab=admin_roles and under `Page owner` I can see an account. This account has the same name as the business.

I've clicked on "Request Release" but this has not ended up in any of the admins notifications, inboxes or anything like this and therefore the release is never done

What steps can I take to find out who are the admins of the business so that they can release the page?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, it's very clear

Comment: No one has answered it, perhaps it is really not clear to others !

Comment: It's literally a step-by-step description of the issue